# Looping through directory and taking files with highest revision number

Tags: vba, excel

I'll preface this by saying I don't have much experience in Excel and VBA code, but I've gone through countless sources looking for this.

I'm attempting to store all files in the current working directory in an array and then looping through that array to find the file with the highest number at the end for each base name.
Example: file1.xlsx, file2.xlsx, anotherfile1.xlsx, anotherfile2.xlsx
would only return file2.xlsx and anotherfile2.xlsx.

This is what I currently have as a starting point:

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet
Dim fileArray() As String
Dim count As Integer
Set count = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsm")

Do Until fileName = ""
    count = count + 1
    ReDim Preserve fileArray(1 To count)
    fileArray(count) = fileName
    fileName = Dir
Loop

'Find unique entries
For Each element In fileArray
    'do stuff here...
Next element
```

The file names are formatted oddly so I'm not sure how to approach this. The file names are like: GENERICNAME-[field I need to compare]-[number].xlsx

Comment: *.xlsm, I was using xlsx as just for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strPath in the below is the most recent file with the name you're looking for.

```
Dim fsoFile As New FileSystemObject
Dim fldFile As Folder: Set fldFile = fsoFile.GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path)
Dim objFile As File
Dim dtFile As Date: dtFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
Dim strPath As String

For Each objFile In fldFile.Files
    If Not objFile.Name Like "*~$*" Then
        If objFile.Name Like "*[file I need to compare]*" _
        And objFile.DateLastModified > dtFile Then
            dtFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            strPath = objFile.Path
        End If
    End If
Next objFile
Set fsoFile = Nothing
Set fldFile = Nothing
```

Comment: If, for whatever reason, your most recent file number doesn't have the most recent date for that name, then instead of referencing objFile.DateLastModified, you could just pull the revision number out of objFile.Name. That would just require a bit of string manipulation.